# Auto populating data from one sheet to another if it matches one certain condition (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, compare, match, populate, auto-populate

I want to compare Column A in Sheet 1 to Column B in Sheet 2, and if they match - copy columns C->E from Sheet 2 into B->D in Sheet 1

I'm new to goole sheets and i'm super lost

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCvGn1NUhQqG53GRqFQiv8Tk7u44jQx_2mxWtzoMiiw/edit#gid=765778823

Tried using vlookup and match functions but kept getting errors. Still don't really grasp the idea behind them yet

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=xlookup(A2,'Sheet 2'!B:B,'Sheet 2'!C:E,)
```

[image]